# how do multiple databases when registering data enter the main database open to the database connection?

Tags: laravel

When I use `protected $ connection = 'vms_db';` I can log in with the data from the db but the register data that goes to the db

I want that I can log in with the db and when the data register enters the main db

```
<?php

namespace VMS;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'id_level', 'email', 'password', 
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
        protected $connection = 'vms_db';
}
```

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]),
    ],

    'vms_db' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host'=> env('DB_VMS_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_VMS_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_VMS_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_VMS_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
        ],
```

Comment: can you share your different connections?

Comment: yes, can share different connections @ChristopheHubert

Comment: can you explain a bit more what data you want in `mysql` connection and what data you want in `vms_db` connection?

Comment: do you want to the data to be stored in both db, when registering?

Comment: I want the data to be stored only in the mysql db, not in the vms_db db @Kuru @ Christophe Hubert

Comment: then remove line `protected $connection = 'vms_db';`  from your model, this code indicate which connection should be used as default when accessing this model